Ubuntu22: Snap store app update action causes popup "authentication was required" yet there's no way to authenticate

If I hit update for Chromium or update-all the popup appears authentication was required" (yes, past tense). I would be able to work with a "you need to authenticate to do this" but no authentication user/password dialog is shown. Nor are there menu options that would take me to a settings panel or equivalent.  How to overcome this permanently?
